# XCode cant recognize IOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, certificate

I'm member of development team, and the team admin sends me a distribution certificate to sign applicattion and send to him,i install it into Keychain  but XCode cannot recognize the certificate, in Organizer there is info that Valid signing identity not found, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the private key from the team admin. Whoever generated the certificate will have the private key in their keychain. They need to export that and send it to you along with the certificate.

Comment: No. The private key is added to the keychain when you generate your signing request. You (or rather, the person who generated the certificate) need to look in the keychain for your certificate, and the private key should be shown as a child item.

Comment: He sends me a private key but i cannot open it, the error is , The contents of this item cannot be retrieved, extension of file is .pem

Comment: Drag it into the keychain. Sometimes you will get an error which you can ignore. If you find the certificate there should be the little "expand" triangle under it, and the private key should be shown as a child item.

Comment: Yes i found a certificate but there is no expander because the private key is not assigned to it, and the same problem occurs when i try to drag it into keychain, maybe the problem is in mac os x version? in my mac is Lion 10.7.4 , in his i think leopard or something else

Comment: maybe he needs to send me also a something like public key , pair of that private key ?

Comment: I assumed he had already sent you the correct certificate. But if you are still having problems, have him select both the certificate and key when he exports them and send you that.

Comment: He sent me a certificate from developer center, just downloaded and sent it to me,the extension of file is .mobileprovision and after sends to me a privet key .pem file, does he need to install certificate from his computer and after it export it and sends to me ?

Comment: The provisioning profile is not the certificate. The certificate is a separate download from the provisioning portal.